# How to return data in the node?

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list

I have to return the head and tail of the list in `GetHead()` and `GetTail()`.

I tried to return head and tail by themselves and get the error:

```
cannot initialize return object of type 'int' with an lvalue of type 'Node<int> *const'
    return tail;
```

I also tried to return `head->value` and `tail->value` and it gives me `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in `string() const`.

```
template<typename T>
class Node
{
private:
    T value;
    Node* prev;
    Node* next;
public:
    Node(T value, Node* prev = NULL, Node* next = NULL);
    friend class List<T>;
};

template<typename T>
class List
{
private:
    Node<T>* head;
    Node<T>* tail;
public:
    List();
    List(const List<T>& src);
    ~List();
    bool IsEmpty() const;
    T GetHead() const;
    T GetTail() const;
    void AddToHead(T v);
    void AddToTail(T v);
    bool RemoveHead();
    bool RemoveTail();

    operator string() const;
    ///////////////////////////////////////////
    // Do not change the above prototype.
    // Add member function(s) below if you need.

    // Do not change the below.
    ///////////////////////////////////////////
};

template<typename T>
Node<T>::Node(T value, Node* prev, Node* next)
{
    this->value = value;
    this->prev = prev;
    this->next = next;
}

template<typename T>
List<T>::operator string() const
{
    if (IsEmpty())
        return "()";
    stringstream os;
    os << "(";
    Node<T>* r = head;
    while (r != tail)
    {
        os << r->value << ",";
        r = r->next;
    }
    os << r->value << ")";
    string str = os.str();
    return str;
}

template<typename T>
List<T>::List()
{
    // make list empty
    head = tail = NULL;
}

template<typename T>
List<T>::List(const List<T>& src)
{
    // make list empty
    head = tail = NULL;

    // copy all contents in src into this
    Node<T>* node = src.head;
    while(node != NULL)
    {
        AddToTail(node->value);
        node = node->next;
    }
}

template<typename T>
bool List<T>::IsEmpty() const
{
    return (head == NULL);
}

///////////////////////////////////////////
// Do not change the above.
// Implement your own member functions below.

template<typename T>
List<T>::~List()
{
    while (!IsEmpty())
        RemoveTail();
}

template<typename T>
void List<T>::AddToTail(T v)
{
    if (IsEmpty())
        head = tail = new Node<T>(v, NULL, NULL);
    else
    {
        head = new Node<T>(v, tail, NULL);
        head->prev->next = tail;
    }
}

template<typename T>
void List<T>::AddToHead(T v)
{
    if (IsEmpty())
        head = tail = new Node<T>(v, NULL, NULL);
    else
    {
        head = new Node<T>(v, NULL, head);
        head->next->prev = head;
    }
}

template<typename T>
bool List<T>::RemoveHead()
{
    if(IsEmpty())
        return false;

    if(head == tail)
    {
            delete tail;
            head = tail = NULL;
            return true;
    }
    else
    {
        head = head->next;
        delete head->prev;
        head->prev = NULL;
        return true;
    }
}

template<typename T>
bool List<T>::RemoveTail()
{
    if(IsEmpty())
        return false;

    if(head == tail)
    {
        delete tail;
        head = tail = NULL;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        tail = tail->prev;
        delete tail->next;
        tail->next = NULL;
        return true;
    }
}

template<typename T>
T List<T>::GetHead() const
{
    return head;
}

template<typename T>
T List<T>::GetTail() const
{
    return tail;
}
```

Comment: And is your list non-empty when you try to access the values? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: You can't just dump your entire code here. You need to isolate the problem and create a [MCVE]. 90% of your code is not needed for the problem you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return `head`/`tail` themselves, because the return type is `T`, so you must return the contents.

As for why you're getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in `string() const` when you use `->value`, there is a major issue in your `AddToTail`. If you have just added one element, then `head` and `tail` are the same pointer, with `prev` and `next` of `NULL`. Then you do:

```
    head = new Node<T>(v, tail, NULL);
```

which makes a new element with a `prev` of `tail` and a `next` of `NULL`, and makes the new element the new `head` (so right off something is odd, since `AddToTail` replaces `head`?!?).

Next,

```
    head->prev->next = tail;
```

takes the new element, finds it's `prev` (the current `tail`/old `head`) and says its `next` is `tail`. So the new `head` has a `next` of `NULL` (it was never set), and `prev` of `tail`, and `tail` itself has a `next` of itself (so if you go back from `head`, then try to go forward, you end up in an infinite loop).

The infinite loop from `tail` isn't even the issue here though. The problem is that the `next` path from `head` hits `NULL` without ever seeing `tail`. If you try to `operator string()` that, it starts from `head` and continues `next` until it reaches `tail` (a reasonable assumption if the list were constructed correctly). But it never reaches `tail`, it just hits `NULL` and dies trying to read `NULL->value`, which is clearly broken.

You need to fix up `AddToTail`, so it creates a legal `List`. And possibly add `assert`s to code that traverses the `List` looking for `tail` to validate that it doesn't hit `NULL` before it hits `tail`. I believe the fix is to change `AddToTail`'s `else` case to:

```
    tail = new Node<T>(v, tail, NULL);
    tail->prev->next = tail;
```

but definitely recheck your logic and add `assert`s appropriately if possible.